# Deploying ASP.Net web app with CruiseControl.Net and SVN -- getting rid of .svn folders

Tags: asp.net, svn, cruisecontrol.net

I have a CruiseControl.Net project set up to build an ASP.Net project, using an <svn> task to pull the latest code from source control.

On a successful build, I use a <buildpublisher> to copy the site to a deployment folder.  My problem is that the buildpublisher is copying everything to the destination folder, including every .svn folder and its contents.  What is the easiest way to strip out the .svn folders before copying to the deployment folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution (if it works for you):
Add a step after the tasks block, before the publisher.

```
<exec>
  <executable>svn.exe</executable>
  <baseDirectory>c:\path_to_my_svn\</baseDirectory>
  <buildArgs>export MyWorkingCopyPath MyTemporaryPath </buildArgs>
</exec>
```

SVN will copy the working copy **MyWorkingCopyPath** (only items under version control) to the destination folder **MyTemporaryPath**.

And in the publisher, you must change the source as the **MyTemporaryPath**.

So, it is only 1 more task to add.

Comment: Thanks.  I used a modified version of this suggestion to get it working.  I actually need to do the export prior to building, and set the build task to use the contents of MyTemporaryPath.  Otherwise, if the export is done after the build, only the original source files are copied, and the Bin folder is left behind.

I wish there was a way for the source control task to do the export automatically, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export from svn for deployment. Use the svn exe with arg=update instead of the usual arg=up setting

This will export your files to your deployment directory, removing the svn folders

Answer (score 0):

I use this lines for a web deployment project. Maybe you can adapt it for your purposes (MsBuild is a big miracle for me)

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
<ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\obj\**\*.*" />
<ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\.svn\**\*.*" />
<ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\.svn\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```